# The mouse touchpad doesn't work after waking from sleep

Tags: laptop, mouse, sleep, touchpad

Hey, I just bought a new laptop, the problem is that when I put my pc to sleep, after it wakes up the mouse touch pad is all messed up and doesn't work so I have to restart my laptop.

Is this some problem with laptop or some other?

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: Please provide more information about your system. Which laptop do you have? Which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Windows doesn't handle sleeping, hibernating, docking/undocking very well.  For starters, make sure that your mouse drivers are current, your BIOS is updated, and you have the latest Windows patches.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my touchpad (Windows 10 64 bits, Toshiba S45 with Synaptics driver)
What I did is this:

- Update Synaptics driver from devmgmt.msc (**Mouse>Update>Update driver**)
- Restart the laptop
- Go again to devmgmt.msc and update the hotkey driver. In my case was Toshiba Hotkey Driver. If you have the OEM driver, give it a try.

[image: Sorry for my spanish image]

- Restart it again and it's done.

Worked for me after several reading in Toshiba, Lenovo and ASUS forums.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't really an answer but I have experienced the same issue.  I'm using a Dell E6500 with Windows 7 x64.  I've read other people have experienced this issue as well using the x86 version.

Not sure if it has anything to do with drivers though as I've had this problem since I bought the laptop and have updated the drivers several times since then.  I'm always checking to see if new drivers are available in hopes they would fix the problem.  Maybe it has something to do with Windows 7.